# How can I invert a complicated bivariate polynomial?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

Here is the function I want to invert:

```
rho(t, p) =             
        + 998.20123 * p ** 0
        - 192.9769495 * p ** 1
        + 389.1238958 * p ** 2
        - 1668.103923 * p ** 3
        + 13522.15441 * p ** 4
        - 88292.78388 * p ** 5
        + 306287.4042 * p ** 6
        - 613838.1234 * p ** 7
        + 747017.2998 * p ** 8
        - 547846.1354 * p ** 9
        + 223446.0334 * p ** 10
        - 39032.85426 * p ** 11
        - 0.20618513 * (t - 20) ** 1
        - 0.0052682542 * (t - 20) ** 2
        + 0.000036130013 * (t - 20) ** 3
        - 0.00000038957702 * (t - 20) ** 4
        + 0.000000007169354 * (t - 20) ** 5
        - 0.000000000099739231 * (t - 20) ** 6
        + 0.1693443461530087 * p ** 1 * (t - 20) ** 1
        - 10.46914743455169 * p ** 2 * (t - 20) ** 1
        + 71.96353469546523 * p ** 3 * (t - 20) ** 1
        - 704.7478054272792 * p ** 4 * (t - 20) ** 1
        + 3924.090430035045 * p ** 5 * (t - 20) ** 1
        - 12101.64659068747 * p ** 6 * (t - 20) ** 1
        + 22486.46550400788 * p ** 7 * (t - 20) ** 1
        - 26055.62982188164 * p ** 8 * (t - 20) ** 1
        + 18523.73922069467 * p ** 9 * (t - 20) ** 1
        - 7420.201433430137 * p ** 10 * (t - 20) ** 1
        + 1285.617841998974 * p ** 11 * (t - 20) ** 1
        - 0.0119301300505701 * p ** 1 * (t - 20) ** 2
        + 0.2517399633803461 * p ** 2 * (t - 20) ** 2
        - 2.170575700536993 * p ** 3 * (t - 20) ** 2
        + 13.53034988843029 * p ** 4 * (t - 20) ** 2
        - 50.29988758547014 * p ** 5 * (t - 20) ** 2
        + 109.635566657757 * p ** 6 * (t - 20) ** 2
        - 142.2753946421155 * p ** 7 * (t - 20) ** 2
        + 108.043594285623 * p ** 8 * (t - 20) ** 2
        - 44.14153236817392 * p ** 9 * (t - 20) ** 2
        + 7.442971530188783 * p ** 10 * (t - 20) ** 2
        - 0.0006802995733503803 * p ** 1 * (t - 20) ** 3
        + 0.01876837790289664 * p ** 2 * (t - 20) ** 3
        - 0.2002561813734156 * p ** 3 * (t - 20) ** 3
        + 1.02299296671922 * p ** 4 * (t - 20) ** 3
        - 2.895696483903638 * p ** 5 * (t - 20) ** 3
        + 4.810060584300675 * p ** 6 * (t - 20) ** 3
        - 4.672147440794683 * p ** 7 * (t - 20) ** 3
        + 2.458043105903461 * p ** 8 * (t - 20) ** 3
        - 0.5411227621436812 * p ** 9 * (t - 20) ** 3
        + 0.000004075376675622027 * p ** 1 * (t - 20) ** 4
        - 0.00000876305857347111 * p ** 2 * (t - 20) ** 4
        + 0.000006515031360099368 * p ** 3 * (t - 20) ** 4
        - 0.00000151578483698721 * p ** 4 * (t - 20) ** 4
        - 0.00000002788074354782409 * p ** 1 * (t - 20) ** 5
        + 0.00000001345612883493354 * p ** 2 * (t - 20) ** 5
```

I usually use Python for my problems, so I tried sympy.solve, but it says that "No algorithms are implemented to solve the equation. "

Are you aware of a tool that could do it?
Or do you even know if there's a way to check if this function is invertible at all?

This function is from https://www.oiml.org/en/publications/bulletin/pdf/oiml_bulletin_july_2015.pdf, page 11 (numbered 9 in the doc)

I want to be able to invert it with respect to either variable.

The rho function is monotonic for a fixed t :

[image: Exampe for t=4]

But not for a fixed p:
[image: Example for p=0.013]

For most of my use cases, the problem is much simpler since t is always 20.

The polynom to inverse then becomes

```
rho(p) =            
    + 998.20123 * p ** 0
    - 192.9769495 * p ** 1
    + 389.1238958 * p ** 2
    - 1668.103923 * p ** 3
    + 13522.15441 * p ** 4
    - 88292.78388 * p ** 5
    + 306287.4042 * p ** 6
    - 613838.1234 * p ** 7
    + 747017.2998 * p ** 8
    - 547846.1354 * p ** 9
    + 223446.0334 * p ** 10
    - 39032.85426 * p ** 11
```

with p in [0; 1]. This is strictly increasing on the intervalle, so it must have a solution for the inverse?

sympy.solve returns the following roots :

```
[
    1.30502635519079, 
    -0.282825358240998 - 0.174919557643158*I, 
    -0.282825358240998 + 0.174919557643158*I, 
    -0.0229786659460121 - 0.441023703545107*I, 
    -0.0229786659460121 + 0.441023703545107*I,
    0.434132824352787 - 0.596683531853141*I, 
    0.434132824352787 + 0.596683531853141*I, 
    0.877616891070605 - 0.549674307713161*I,
    0.877616891070605 + 0.549674307713161*I, 
    1.20382263269017 - 0.326905440295712*I, 
    1.20382263269017 + 0.326905440295712*I
 ]
```

of which only the first one is real. What do i do with it?

Comment: Hi! Are you trying to solve for $t$ or $p$?

Comment: Both, separately. I'm more after a method than a solution, because I'll have to apply it to variations of this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is impossible to write down a formula for the inverse function of a polynomial with degree $\ge 5$. This result is known as [Abel's impossibility theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

For example, if you want to solve $\rho(t,p) = y$ for $t$, there is no formula we can write down in terms of radicals that works. For this reason, you will need to resort to numerical methods, such as [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), to find a solution.

It also can be difficult to prove that solutions exist. Because $\rho(t,p)$ is degree $6$ in $t$, and the $t^6$ term has a negative coefficient, we can tell that for each $p$ fixed, $\rho(t,p)$ has a maximum value, and therefore there exists $y_p\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\rho(t,p) = y$ has a solution (not necessarily unique) if and only if $y\le y_p$. Finding $y_p$ is a simple optimization problem, so it suffices to look for solutions to $\frac{d}{dt} \rho(t,p) = 0$, which amounts to solving a degree $4$ polynomial in $t$. This is [theoretically possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_formula) to do with radicals, but that's actually less efficient than using Newton's method to solve. For fixed $t$, $\rho(t,p)$ is a degree $11$ polynomial, so $\rho(t,p)=y$ always has at least one (and at most $11$) solutions for $p$.

---

When $t=20$, as you observe $\rho$ becomes a degree $11$ polynomial. Since it is decreasing on $[0,1]$, it has an inverse function, hence for each $y$ in its range, there is a unique $p\in[0,1]$ that solves $y=\rho(p)$. The roots don't help you too much to find an inverse function; the real root is the unique real solution to $\rho(p)=0$. Abel's theorem applies here too, so there is no closed for expression for the inverse function of $\rho$ in this case either, so you will need to resort to numeric methods here too.

Comment: I generated values for p in [0; 1] with 0.001 steps and t in [-10, 60] with 0.1 steps. For a given t, or a given p (a line or a column of the generated table), the function is monotonous (idk if it's the English term, it's always ascending). So there must be a unique solution in the intervalle I'm interested in, right?

Comment: Yea, if it's monotonic then there's a unique solution. Btw, monotonous / monotonic / increasing all work in this context, but I think (in my area of math at least) "monotonic" is the most common.

Comment: It's actually not monotonic for a given p, my bad.

Comment: That's because it's degree $6$ in $t$. It may turn out to be monotonic on the specific intervals you happen to be working on though, which you can use to your advantage.

Comment: I have updated the question, but the problem has evolved now, so I don't know if I did good or if I should ask a new one

Comment: OK I have updated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: FYI I have continued this problem here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271197/use-solve-solutions-as-function-when-there-are-multiple-solutions-on-distinct-do

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately for me, computational questions are outside of my realm of expertise.